# what's the meaning of - He looks like he's on something

Tags: phrases

In the context of him being angry and disoriented, it means he's on some drug, right?

Google didn't help me

Comment: I think it can be interpreted as being under effect of "something"(medicine etc)

Comment: idiom: to be on drugs [legal or otherwise]

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

(very short answer.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the thefreedictionary.com:

> be on
>
> 1. To be taking or under the influence of drugs (legal or illegal). They've got me on a load of antibiotics to fight off the infection. He
>      acts so crazy that sometimes I wonder if he's on drugs!

So, yes, it seems to mean exactly that in this context.

It could also mean other things in different contexts:

> 2. To be performing or displayed, as on a stage, on television, or in a venue. That new play is on at the National Theater this evening.
>      They're showing my favorite film on TV tonight! I hear there's a great
>      new band on at the bar down the road.
> 3. To perform exceptionally well or impressively. The home team is really on tonight, it looks like they'll have an easy victory.
> 4. To be in support of, have interest in, or plan to participate in some activity or thing. Yeah, I'm on for having a few drinks later!
>      Mary said she's on to go to a movie tonight.
> 5. To do something as planned or according to schedule. Are you still on to pick me up from the airport tomorrow? The meeting is on at five
>      o'clock.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on